# How to add change (in unemployment rate) to dependent variable

Tags: self-study, econometrics, gretl

[image]I'm an Econometrics beginner and I'm sorry if the title is confusing. I basically have a variable “unemp” which gives me the unemployment, the dependent variable of this model should be the change in unemployment. How do I proceed? I'm working in Gretl and tried defining a new variable with unemployment(t)-unemployment(t-1)/unemployment(t-1) but it delivers the wrong results. Can anyone help me here? How would the variable economic growth be interpreted? More economic growth leads to higher change in unemployment?

Model: change in unemployment = B0 + B1 economic growth + u

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to look into values, I am not sure what is the type unemployment variable here. Let's assume it contains two values 0 and 1 where 0 mean employed and 1 is unemployed. And economic growth is a continuous variable with real values. So you can use Logistic regression to find if the economic growth resulted in employment or not and then compare the previous employed state for this. This would work if the unemployment variable is categorical. If you provide more insight into the data, I can provide a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that it is a time series with quarterly values. The values of “unemp” go from 0-100, basically how many people are unemployed, they are not necessarily a percentage but are rather given as units. So the first few values of unemployment are for example 71, 68, 93, 7, 31,... Does what you said still work if unemployment is non categorical?

Comment: Ok, if it is a time series, then you need to first check if it can be modelled by stationary or non stationary process. Then you can use Auto regressive or Moving Average or ARIMA model to predict future unemployment. Also check if the time series is seasonal or not. This will give you a better idea to model your data.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of atleast 5 rows of your data?

Comment: You can view this link for more insight, https://david-hasan.medium.com/time-series-analysis-arima-forecasting-model-using-python-9a7874cefcd7

Comment: I added the data as a picture in the question above. I’m not sure if I need to predict future employment, I just need to estimate the coefficients by OLS. However I’m not sure how to write Δunemp as a dependent variable before doing the regression as I only have unemp.

Comment: Ok, so you can create a new column for change in unemployment with change = unemp(t) - unemp(t-1). The first row you have to consider a baseline and  set it to 0. The it should be easy for you to perform OLS. If you want a percentage, you can do change = (unemp(t) - unemp(t-1))/unemp(t-1)  which you have already mentioned before. But you're getting wrong results. What seems wrong in the results?

Comment: Do you think I can do this in Gretl or is it better to do it in Excel?

Comment: Also how would we interpret growth in this case? A higher growth leads to a bigger change in unemployment?

Comment: I have not used Gretl. I would do it in R or python. You should stick to what you're more comfortable in.

Comment: Thank you so much